# Spying has never been easier

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

Spying has never been easier with me, 
Boats have use of what's inside me,
Shout I do not, even when teeth may enter me.

I'll be happy to share an interest
With many who look alike - unlike the rest,
Guard against secrets... I do my best.

Who/What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're a

> lock.

Spying has never been easier with me,

> In the age of the net, lock picking to gain access to a restricted room/cabinet is now trivial.

Boats have use of what's inside me,

> The central part of a lock is called a [hull](https://www.lysator.liu.se/mit-guide/figure2.1.gif), which is [also a part of a boat](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=boat%20hull&tbs=imgo:1).

Shout I do not, even when teeth may enter me.

> Keys have teeth.

I'll be happy to share an interest
With many who look alike - unlike the rest,

> Identical keys (duplicates) can open the lock, but other keys cannot.

Guard against secrets... I do my best.

> That's what locks are for!

Comment: Great answer - good thinking! Extremely close to what I had in mind. Debatable who's is better answer... Try and update the answer with a second option and I'll accept this answer...

Comment: I posted my answer - I will accept yours though if you can convince me that it is better than mine... Awaiting your response...

Comment: @Ben, I think it was a great puzzle and they're both great answers. As asker, I think you should accept the answer you like more, regardless of how the community feels.

Answer (score 3):

Who/What am I?

> The Net/Internet

Spying has never been easier with me

> The internet certainly seems to help the NSA...

Boats have use of what's inside me

> The fish inside a net

Shout I do not, even when teeth may enter me

> Well, it's a "thing", so it can't really be hurt.

I'll be happy to share an interest
With many who look alike - unlike the rest,
Guard against secrets... I do my best.

> Again, internet. It allows the sharing of interests between anonymous people, while staying anonymous isn't always as easy as it seems ("I do my best.")

Answer (score 2):

I am a:

> Keyhole!

Spying has never been easier with me,

> Looking through the keyhole - great way to spy!

Boats have use of what's inside me,

> Locks are a key feature on canals for barges

Shout I do not, even when teeth may enter me.

> Keys have teeth

I'll be happy to share an interest
With many who look alike - unlike the rest,

> Only keys that are the same can unlock me

Guard against secrets... I do my best.

> I enable the door to be locked!

Comment: If you choose to go with this answer, I would recommend changing the puzzle to *boats have use of what I'm inside* since a keyhole is inside a lock, not the other way around.

Comment: @user1717828  You're right! I'm a doofus! Good arg. I'm going to accept your answer. (I feel it's a bit of a cop-out to now change the question and accept my own answer...)

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> A safe

Spying has never been easier with me,

> Safes contain sensitive information and can be helpful to spies

Boats have use of what's inside me,

> Safes have locks, which is like the hull of the ship

Shout I do not, even when teeth may enter me.

> The lock(s)/key have teeth

I'll be happy to share an interest

> Find the right person, and all the stuff in a safe can be released

With many who look alike - unlike the rest,

> It is in your best interest to show what is inside or how to open the safe with people you trust. In war, with people on your side

Guard against secrets... I do my best

> Safes protect sensitive/valuable material from getting into the worng hands